# Database Project Documentation and Tutorials

Tags: visual-studio-2013, database-project

I cant seem to find the msdn documentation and tutorials on the 2013 Database Project.

Can someone post links to the documentation and tutorials.

Comment: What do you mean 2013 Database Project? VS 2013 does not have does not have database project types like the previous versions of VS.

Comment: The Project type is called: SQL Server Database Project.

Comment: I blogged quite a bit about using SQL/DB Projects on my blog - http://schottsql.blogspot.com/2013/10/all-ssdt-articles.html.  That could get you started.

Comment: This project type actually comes from SQL Server Data Tools, hence the confusion.

Comment: Ok, I see. I have SQL Server Data Tools installed.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can get more information at the official team blog called [SQL Server Data Tools Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/).
2. Another good resource is this introductory video on Channel 9 titled [Introducing SQL Server Database Projects Tooling in Visual Studio 2013](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Launch-2013/VS111)
3. MSDN documentation [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272686%28VS.103%29.aspx)